# Generate spells based on date based records, with additional restrictions on continuation of spell

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a variation on the merging spells of continuous dates problem.

As well as needing to have continuous dates, records with spells of the same absence type are classed as continuous if there is an indicator "2" in a field called Commentid in the next record. If this is blank, then they are classed as two separate spells even if the same absence type. And, just to complicate it further(!), if the FIRST record in the overall span has a Commentid of "3" then I need to output data in another column (Predate) which has the span start date-1 (otherwise leave this column blank).

eg.

```
Person  From        To          Abs    Commentid    
1     01/01/2018    03/01/2018  Sick    
1     04/01/2018    06/01/2018  Sick    3
1     07/01/2018    10/01/2018  Sick    2
1     11/01/2018    13/01/2018  Sick    2   
1     01/02/2018    03/02/2018  Vac 
1     04/02/2018    11/02/2018  Vac     2
1     12/02/2018    15/02/2018  Vac
```

In above I would expect output:

```
Person  From        To          Abs     Predate
1       01/01/2018  03/01/2018  Sick    
1       04/01/2018  13/01/2018  Sick    03/01/2018
1       01/02/2018  11/02/2018  Vac 
1       12/02/2018  15/02/2018  Vac
```

I've looked at various other similar problems. I can get spells based purely on the dates/absence type, but the additional requirements around the Commentid make me think that something else is needed. It's difficult to include all the exact code I have used so far as the source data is actually being pulled from multiple tables. But I have an initial CTE (prepdata) which includes in the select clause a column like:

```
,island = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.person     ORDER BY ri.startdtm)
       - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.person,  pyc.abs ORDER BY ri.startdtm)
```

and then after the CTE a simple select:

```
SELECT person, abs,
  [from] = MIN([REQUEST_START_DATE]),
  [to]   = MAX([REQUEST_END_DATE])
FROM
prepdata
GROUP BY person,  abs, island
```

Any help appreciated into how to incorporate the Commentid field requirements.

TIA, Nycoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data:

```
set dateformat dmy
declare @prepdata table (Person int, [From] date, [To] date, [Abs] varchar(10), CommentID int)

insert @prepdata values
(1,'01/01/18','03/01/18','Sick',null),
(1,'04/01/18','06/01/18','Sick',3),
(1,'07/01/18','10/01/18','Sick',2),
(1,'11/01/18','13/01/18','Sick',2),
(1,'01/02/18','03/12/18','Vac',null),
(1,'04/02/18','11/12/18','Vac',2),
(1,'12/02/18','15/02/18','Vac',null)
```

Proposed solution:

```
select Person, FromX as [From], MAX(ToX) as [To], [Abs], MAX(PreDate) as PreDate
from (
select Person
    ,[Abs]
    ,case CommentID 
        when 2 then
            (select MAX([From]) from @prepdata
                where Person=p.Person and [Abs]=p.[Abs]
                  and IsNull(CommentId,3)=3 and [From]<p.[From])
        else [From]
    end as FromX
    ,[To] as ToX
    ,case CommentID
        when 3 then
            (select MAX([To]) from @prepdata
                where Person=p.Person and [Abs]=p.[Abs]
                  and CommentID is null and [To]<p.[From])
        else null
    end as PreDate
from @prepdata p
) p1
group by Person, FromX, [Abs]
```

Comment: Thanks @Xabi  This looks good. I didn't think it could be done without a CTE! I'll plug it into my existing code and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Xabi the solution isn't quite right. The part about the commentid=3, needs to return the spell start date-1 day. 

So using this sample data the answer is correct (03/01/2018), but the code is actually picking up the END date of the previous record which just also happens to be 03/01/2018 in this sample data. But if you change the end date of the first record to 02/01/2018, then the second record gets output with predate = 02/01/2018 but it should be 03/01/2018 - one less than the output record startdate. Do you know how to adjust the predate to use the span start date-1? Thanks.

Comment: Ok.... I think I may have fixed it.... I've changed the table declare to use datetimes (to allow the subtract 1). And I've updated the final CASE statement to 

    ,case CommentID
        when 3 then p.[From]-1
        else null
    end as PreDate

Initial testing looks good but I'll do some further validation, thanks.

Comment: If always when CommentID=3 the PreDate is [From]-1 then the case would be: `case CommentID when 3 then DateAdd(dd,-1,[From]) else null end as PreDate` instead of searching the previous date inside the table. Not need to change `date` to `datetime`